# how to maintain Long equations in Iguanatex without breaking line (powerpoint)

Tags: math, latex, powerpoint, tex

How to maintain long equations in the box, when long equations are typed they are splitting into two lines. How to get long equations in one line or how to increase the width of the equation box ?

[equation breaks - how to get this in one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOAga.png)

[code for the above image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR8GJ.png)

Comment: Here is the IguanaTex support group, you may get an answer there: https://groups.google.com/g/iguanatex

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in two ways:

### 1 Change the document class to `standalone`

> ```
> \documentclass{standalone}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{xcolor}
> \usepackage{empheq}
> \pagestyle{empty}
> \begin{document}
> \textbf{Question 1:} Find the Modulus and argument of the Complex Number, $\sqrt{3}+i$
> \end{document}
> ```

### 2 Adapt the width of the document using the `geometry` package

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{xcolor}
> \usepackage{empheq}
> \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
> \pagestyle{empty}
> \begin{document}
> \textbf{Question 1:} Find the Modulus and argument of the Complex Number, $\sqrt{3}+i$
> \end{document}
> ```